# How to use finished callback function in nativescript-texttospeech?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, text-to-speech, nativescript-vue

How to order nativescript texttospeech messages with a callback function?

How to use finished callback function?

nativescript-texttospeech has a `finishedCallback` property in SpeakOptions.

**I need TTS to read texts one by one that's all.**

```
talk("First message");
talk("Second message");
talk("Last message");
```

```vue
<template>
  <Page>
    <ActionBar title="Speak Promises Component" />
    <StackLayout>
      <Label :text="speakoptions.text" col="0" row="0" />
      <Button text="start" @tap="start" />
    </StackLayout>
  </Page>
</template>

<script >
import {  TNSTextToSpeech,  SpeakOptions as speakoptions } from "nativescript-texttospeech";
let TTS = new TNSTextToSpeech();

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      speakoptions: {
        text: " ",
        locale: "en-GB",
        finishedCallback: "" // what kind of function it should be?
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    start: async function() {
      await this.talk("First message");
      await this.talk("Second message");
      await this.talk("Last message");
    },
    talk: function(message) {
      this.speakoptions.text = message;
      return TTS.speak(this.speakoptions);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped >
</style>
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: You have to use `finishedCallback` function, the promise just ensures speaking started successfully.

Comment: May be I should re-ask question. Should I edit my question. How to use `finishedCallback`?

Comment: It's very straight forward, just pass a function and that will be called when speaking is done.

Comment: what kind of function it should be?  do I have to change talk function as well? `talk("Second message",next)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your own promise, that should help

```
talk: function(message) {
  var speakOptions = { ...this.speakoptions, text: message };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     speakOptions.finishedCallback = resolve;
     TTS.speak(speakOptions)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Manoj , now it just reads "first message". How will I go to next await function?

Comment: Which platform you are testing it with? Do you have a sample repo.

Comment: https://github.com/kaanna/talk-one-by-one  
It's really strange.When I first run everything works as expected. After I make any change "like comment out any message" it just reads first message. 
.Refreshing application on device breaks something and **it just reads _first message_.

Comment: Make sure it works on release mode, I don't work quite often with Vue but I was told it has issues with HMR often.

Comment: yes `tns run --no-hmr` solved problem, thank you very much.